# Is there a Django ModelField that allows for multiple choices, aside from ManyToMany?

Tags: python, django, forms

I'd like the user to be able to make multiple selections via the admin interface, and store the result as a list of comma-separated values. A select-multiple or a list of checkboxes would be great. However, I don't need the items in this list of values to refer to any models in particular... I just want a text list of items, plain and simple, hence I don't think the ManyToManyField is the one I'm looking for. What's the quickest way to do this in Django?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Model MultipleChoice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440861/django-model-multiplechoice)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a django snippet which does just this: [multiple choice model field](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1200/). It says:

> Usually you want to store multiple
>   choices as a manytomany link to
>   another table. Sometimes however it is
>   useful to store them in the model
>   itself. This field implements a model
>   field and an accompanying formfield to
>   store multiple choices as a
>   comma-separated list of values, using
>   the normal CHOICES attribute.

Answer (score 4):

Django-multiselectfield does what you require:

https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield

It's inspired by the snippet that Alexander mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This django snippet accomplishes the same with a much smaller footprint.

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/23/

make sure to update those imports since they are pre version 1.0