# MultipleChoiceFileld in ModelForm will only submit when default option available but nothing is selected

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to use a `MultipleChoiceField` with a ModelForm but am obviously implementing it wrong.

There are two linked? issues:

- The question only submits of the user selects nothing
- The question displays the default option "------" which i want to remove

  - If I remove the "-----" by removing `blank=True` the question will not submit at all, see image below.

[image]

If anyone can tell me what I am going wrong it would be greatly appriciated.

**modles.py**

```
ELECTIONS = (
    ('NONE', 'None'),
    ('LOCAL', 'Local elections'),
    ('STATE', 'State elections e.g. Governorship'),
    ('NATIONAL', 'National elections e.g. Congress and Senate'),
    ('PRESIDENTIAL', 'Presidential elections'),
    ('OTHER', 'Other'),
    ('DONT_KNOW', "Don't know"),
    )

elections = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, blank=True, default=None, choices = ELECTIONS, verbose_name = 'Which elections do you regularly vote in or intend to vote in? Select all that apply.')
```

**forms.py**

```
class SurveyFormD(forms.ModelForm): # Political Viewpoints

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['liberal_conservative', 'democrat_republican', 'voting_rights', 'elections']        

        widgets = {'liberal_conservative' : forms.RadioSelect,
                   'democrat_republican' : forms.RadioSelect,
                   'voting_rights' : forms.RadioSelect,
                   'elections' : forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a `MultipleChoiceField` in your form, but you have a `CharField` in your model.  A `CharField` stores strings, not lists, so your model is expecting a *single* (string) value from the list of choices, not the list `[u'LOCAL', u'NATIONAL', u'PRESIDENTIAL']` that your `CheckboxSelectMultiple` is returning.

You could make `elections` a `ManyToMany` field and thus store multiple values in the single field `elections`.

Or check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440861/django-model-multiplechoice) for further clarification.