# Error saving django model MultipleChoiceField checkbox field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have a checkbox choice field like this:

```
models.py
TYPE_CHOICES = (
       ('s', 'small'),
       ('m', 'medium'),
       ('b', 'big'),
     )
class Post(models.Model) :
    size = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length="3", choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
```

So in the admin form:

```
class MainContent(forms.ModelForm):
    size = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

But when I saving the form it give me this error:

> Select a valid choice. ['s', 'm', 'b'] is not one of the available
>   choices.

So, what is the problem?

### UPDATE

My apology, this question was not given enough info, let me explain more.

The reason I want a checkbox input is because I want it able to store multiple values in the single field (one column). Perhaps the data can be serialized (or comma separated),

Since the TYPE_CHOICES is static and will not changed in the future, I am not planning to use ManytoMany.

Also I want it able to display in the template easily by the language language.

Hope this is clear enough.

Comment: Your setup sounds weird. Your model has `size` as `CharField`, but how come in your `Form` you use `MultipleChoiceField`?

Comment: i think you was pass a list, not a 's', 'm' or 'b'.  you cant save all. just one.

Comment: @ShangWang are Right, that's the problem.

Comment: Do you want to have multiple sizes on one `Post` or to choose only one `size` among the choices?

Answer (score 0):

> Presumably, you want a single column in a table that is storing
>   multiple values. This will also force you to think about how to will
>   serialize - for example, you can't simply do comma separated if you
>   need to store strings that might contain commas.
>
> However, you are best using a solution like one of the following:
>
> https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multiselectfield/
>
> https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-select-multiple-field/

This answer solve your problem, you are try to store a list of strings, but the charfield.

[Link to post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440861/django-model-multiplechoice)

or try use [ChoiceField](http://dhttps://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField)

Answer (score 0):

You're using a CharField in your model but in your form you use MultipleChoiceField, for a ModelForm it's an incompatible type because it wouldn't know what to do if the user chooses more than one option, I would recommend using a catalog and a ManyToManyField:

**If you want to select more than one size for a Post model:**

models.py

```
class SizesCatalog(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.description

class Post(models.Model) :
    size = models.ManyToMany(SizesCatalog, db_table='post_sizes')
```

admin form

```
class MainContent(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

**if you want to select just one size for just one:**

models.py

```
class SizesCatalog(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.description

class Post(models.Model) :
    size = models.ManyToMany(SizesCatalog)
```

admin form

```
class MainContent(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

That way you let Django deal with your problems and in a future you could even update your sizes in a better way