# Prefill MultipleChoiceField django

Tags: django, checkbox, django-forms

Lets say I have the following model

```
class Application(models.Model):
    occupation = models.TextField()
```

and form

```
class ApplicationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['occupation'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=OCCUPATION_CHOICES, widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    class Meta:
        model = Application
```

When I use it with a instance (for example via admin) the choices are not selected.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** *Clarification:* When I select some choices, I hit submit it saves the data. They look like `['undergraduate', 'postdoc']` in the database. But they are not checked in the form anymore.

Comment: Your `super` call is wrong, it should be  `super(ApplicationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: No, in python3 you don't have to write it that way. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super

Comment: You forgot to add `choices=OCCUPATION_CHOICES` to the `occupation` field in your `Application`model.

Comment: If I add it there I get the following error: Select a valid choice. ['postdoc', 'professor'] is not one of the available choices.

Comment: What does `OCCUPATION_CHOICES` contain?

Comment: it is a list of tuples: [('postdoc', 'Post-Doc'), ('professor', 'Professor / Teacher'),...]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get it working like this.

```
import ast
class ApplicationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('instance'):
            kwargs['initial'] = {
                'occupation': ast.literal_eval(kwargs.get('instance').occupation or '[]'),
            }
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Application
        widgets = {
            'occupation': CheckboxSelectMultiple(choices=OCCUPATION_CHOICES),
        }
```

Thanks go to **RodrigoDela** who made me realize what I was doing wrong and pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit:* A `TextField` **cannot** store multiple choices. Take a look at this:
[Django Model MultipleChoice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440861/django-model-multiplechoice)

Either you use this, or you override your forms, so that these can parse the `instance.occupation` content into their `form.occupation` field.

Comment: Select a valid choice. ['postdoc', 'professor'] is not one of the available choices. (again)

Comment: That error comes up in the admin? Because the code works for me. You did `makemigrations` and migrated?

Comment: Yes it is in the admin and I did the migrations.