# A Select Widget with fields as checkboxes with multiple options possible

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following model:

```
class Owner(models.Model)

country = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=COUNTRIES, default=COUNTRIES_DEFAULT)

COUNTRIES is compose of tuples:

COUNTRIES = (
    ('afg', 'Afghanistan'),
    ('ala', 'Aland Islands'),
    ('alb', 'Albania'),
    ('dza', 'Algeria'),
    ('asm', 'American Samoa'),
    ....... )
```

For FrontEnd, I need to show a Widget, and for each country to have a checkbox.
A Person/User can select multiple Countries.

I presume I need to use a custom widget, but I don't know where to start inherit for Field/Widget and make the query in the database.

--- **Why is not a duplicate of Django Multiple Field questio**n ----

**I don't need a new Model field**, or to store it in the database and is not a many to many relation, so something like the package `django-multiselectfield` is not useful.

The ModelField is storing just one value, but in the form will appear values from the tuple.I added just to see the correspondence.

Instead I need to be just a Form Field, to get the values, and query the database. Like get all owners that resides in USA and UK.

Also **is not looking like Select2, I need to respect design**. As functionality is like in the image:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Model MultipleChoice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440861/django-model-multiplechoice)

Comment: @malberts, I don't need the same thing, I updated the question to be more clear

Comment: So you are just looking for a form field with multiple choices using checkboxes?

Comment: @malberts yes, where I can customize the widget, and then retrieve all the values. Get the names of the countries and then do a queryset to get all owners that resides in one of the countries. I just query the Country field in the Model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Form you must define a `MultipleChoiceField` with the `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget:

```
countries = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=COUNTRIES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

This will give you a list of multiple choice checkboxes. You can style that yourself to appear with a scrollbar if you don't want to show a long list.

Here is an example from the Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/widgets/#setting-arguments-for-widgets