# How To Add MultipleChoiceField To Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a **CharField** field in my model. I want to display it as a **MultipleChoiceField** widget in the Django admin site. **models.py:**

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    categories = models.CharField()
    ...
```

I've created a custom form widget in **forms.py**:

```py
from django import forms

CATEGORIES_LIST = [
    ('for_him', 'For Him'),
    ('for_her', 'For Her'),
    ('for_kids', 'For Kids'),
]

class Categories(forms.Form):
    categories = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        choices=CATEGORIES_LIST,
    )
```

Not quite sure what to do next. How do I connect this widget with Django Admin for my Product model? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is not that straight forward using a CharField and putting multiple options in it so you must first find a way to serialize and restore your data to the model take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440861/django-model-multiplechoice).

if you are on a postgres database you could do it this way (thanks to postgres array fields you don't have the serializing and restoring data headache)

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
class ChoiceArrayField(ArrayField):
    """
    A field that allows us to store an array of choices.

    Uses Django 1.9's postgres ArrayField
    and a MultipleChoiceField for its formfield.

    Usage:

        choices = ChoiceArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=..., choices=(...,)), default=[...])
    """

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {
            'form_class': forms.MultipleChoiceField,
            'choices': self.base_field.choices,
        }
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(ArrayField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

and then you can use ChoiceArrayField on your model

Update:

So to use this on your model you can do it like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    categories = ChoiceArrayField(max_length=8, choices=CATEGORIES_LIST, default=['for_him', 'for_her'])
```

Comment: Thank you! However, can you please kindly show me how to use ArrayField on a live example, what exactly should be added to my models.py? I'm a bit lost. Thanks again for helping me.

Comment: @Android_Minsky edited the answer and added an example

Answer (score 0):

### Use MultipleChoiceField in Admin Form

in your `forms.py`

```
class Categories(forms.Form):
    categories = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        choices=CATEGORIES_LIST,
    )
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Categories, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if kwargs.get('instance'):
            self.initial['categories'] = eval(self.initial['categories'])
```

It'll detect your choices and auto-fill the boxes use select after update the page.

Answer (score 0):

2023 (Django 4.2) version:

The answer by @amir-heshmati is broken because `ArrayField` injects a `base_field` argument which is not supported by `MultipleChoiceField`.

I made some changes to make it work and added some finishing touches.

```py
class ChoiceArrayField(ArrayField):
    """
    Postgres Array field with choices.
    This will change the default form field to `MultipleChoiceField`.

    Usage:
    1) `base_field` should match the type of choices.
    2) `choices` should be specified on the `ChoiceArrayField` instead of inside `base_field`.
    3) `default` is supported (also specify on the `ChoiceArrayField`); either a single value or a list/tuple is ok.
    4) The django admin hint for M2M fields is appended to help text when rendering the form.

    Example:

        class MyChoices(models.TextChoices):
            A = ('a', 'A')
            B = ('b', 'B')

        my_choices = ChoiceArrayField(
            CharField(max_length=16),
            choices=MyChoices.choices,
            default=MyChoices.A,
        )
    """

    def _initial(self):
        """
        MultipleChoiceField wants a callable for `initial` arg.
        """
        return self.default

    FORM_HELP_TEXT_APPEND = _('Hold down “Control”, or “Command” on a Mac, to select more than one.')

    @cached_property
    def _help_text(self) -> str:
        if self.help_text:
            return f'{self.help_text} {self.FORM_HELP_TEXT_APPEND}'
        else:
            return self.FORM_HELP_TEXT_APPEND

    def formfield(
            self,
            *,
            form_class=None,
            choices_form_class=None,
            **kwargs,
    ):
        if form_class is not None or choices_form_class is not None:
            # do not attempt override
            return super().formfield(form_class=form_class, **kwargs)

        return MultipleChoiceField(**{
            'required': not self.blank,
            'label': capfirst(self.verbose_name),
            'choices': self.choices,
            'initial': self._initial,
            'help_text': self._help_text,
            **kwargs,
        })
```