# How to create 2 roles for the same user in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGGjb.jpg)
I am creating a job portal system where a user can either be a employee or employer.This is my models.py in account app in django, it is not working.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

from account.managers import CustomUserManager

JOB_TYPE = (
    ('M', "Male"),
    ('F', "Female"),

)

ROLE = (
    ('employer', "Employer"),
    ('employee', "Employee"),
)

class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=False,
                              error_messages={
                                  'unique': "A user with that email already exists.",
                              })
    role = models.CharField(choices=ROLE,  max_length=10)
    gender = models.CharField(choices=JOB_TYPE, max_length=1)


    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.first_name+ ' ' + self.last_name
    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

Comment: Exactly *what* is not working?

Comment: that role of employer and employee in not visible in the frontend...

Comment: How do you render this in the frontend?

Comment: Please show us also your view for that model and if you are using REST framework its serializer

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you are going for but possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440861/django-model-multiplechoice

Comment: def employee_registration(request):

    form = EmployeeRegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form = form.save()
        return redirect('account:login')
    context={
        
            'form':form
        }
    return render(request,'account/employee-registration.html',context)

Comment: Hello @912_AnjaliJha please [edit] your question and add this code in your question.